# Send sql server job alert only when a query has rows to return

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, alerting

I have a query that checks if we've made sales of a particular stock item

```
select * from merchand_history where stock_code = 'zzz007' and create_timestamp >= getdate() order by create_timestamp desc
```

I'd like to have a sql job that emails a user (I guess using the alert mechanism) but only if there are rows returned by that query.

I can't think how to do this and submit to the hivemind. I really need a sql only solution...

Comment: Just a quick clarification, does the email need to send the rows returned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try building a stored procedure something like below and schedule it to run as a job:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_send_merchant_email] 
as


Begin

declare @recordCount int 


select @recordCount = isnull(count(*), 0)
from merchand_history 
where stock_code = 'zzz007' and create_timestamp >= getdate() 
order by create_timestamp desc



IF (@recordCount > 0)
begin



EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'YourProfile',
    @recipients = 'recipients@yourcompany.com',
    @query = 'select * from merchand_history 
                where stock_code = ''zzz007'' and create_timestamp >= getdate() 
                order by create_timestamp desc' ,
      @subject = 'Merchant Email ',
       @Body = 'Email Merchant..... ' ,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;

End
else
begin

      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'YourProfile',
       @recipients = 'recipients@yourcompany.com', 
            @BODY = 'No data returned ', 
            @subject = 'Merchant Email'

End
End;
```

Comment: perfect - cheers!

Comment: I'm glad this helped.